# How to get the div that has a duplicated id using querySelector()?

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

I have a `<div>` and a `<video>` that both have the same id:

```
<div id="id1">
    Some content
</div>
<video id="id1">
    <source></source>
</video>
```

It is not possible for me to change the IDs of the div or the video. The div is created automatically by the `video.js` library, which gives both the div and the video elements the same id.

How do I target the div element alone? (Using `querySelector()` or similar)

Comment: id's should be unique.

Comment: This is malformed HTML.  If you fix your HTML to make your IDs unique, the problem then becomes trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prefix the id name with the element, but don't do this - correct your badly formed HTML instead.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#id1')
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.querySelectorAll("div#id1")[0].style.backgroundColor='red';
  document.querySelectorAll("video#id1")[0].style.backgroundColor='green';
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
Some content
</div>
<video id="id1">
<source></source>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use an id twice.

```
<div id="id1">
  Some content
</div>
<video id="id2">
  <source></source>
</video>

var el = document.querySelector('#id2');
```

See [W3 Docs:](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.

Comment: The div is dynamically created with video.js using the same video id. So both the video and the div should have the same id

Comment: Just my personal opinion, but to me that sounds like a bad library

Comment: fwiw video.js does not duplicate ids. You'd end up with `<div id="id1" ...><video id="id1_html5_api"...>`

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique. <sup>[specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)</sup>

If the HTML code is yours, you should fix this first.

On the other hand, if what you are doing is on a site you cannot modify (e.g. userscript):

`querySelector('div#id1')`, or, `getElementById('id1')` have no stander behavior when there are duplicate `id`s. So you may need

```
document.querySelector('div[id="id1"]')
```